# Solve partial differential equations (PDEs) analytically

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, partial-derivative

Actually, I know a little about PDEs.
I am working on a project which I need to solve a system of PDEs.

My Question is this: How can I solve these systems of equations analytically?

> $$\rho\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}-B\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}+A\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}=0$$
>
> $$\rho c \frac{\partial\theta}{\partial t}-k\frac{\partial^2 \theta}{\partial x^2}+P\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x \partial t} =0$$

And the initial and boundary conditions are:

> $$u(x,0)=0$$
> $$u'(x,0)=0$$
> $$\theta(x,0)=0$$
> $$u(0,t)=0$$
> $$u(L,t)=0$$
> $$\theta(0,t)=1-exp(-\omega\cdot t)$$
> $$\theta(L,0)=0$$

P.s:

I have these assumptions:

> $$u(x,t)=F(x)\cdot e^{\lambda.t}$$
> $$\theta(x,t)=G(x)\cdot e^{\lambda\cdot t}$$

But at the end, the unknown constants are more than the conditions so I can't evaluate them.

Thank you.

Comment: In the 2nd eq you have 2 terms the same. Is that right?

Comment: Your ansatz/assumptions most likely will not work. While the second equation indeed looks like the heat equation for $\theta$, your boundary condition at $0$ will not allow exponential decay for $\theta$. Also the first equation looks more like a wave equation, driven by $\partial_x \theta$ so one should expect $u$ to oscillate in time instead of decaying. Apart from this, I would suggest developing both functions as a Fourier series in x, as the equations will then turn into ODEs, although the boundary condition may prove tricky.

Comment: @user121049 I am sorry. I edited the second equation.

Comment: @mlk Thanks for your answer. yes, u function is like a wave and can oscillate.How can I use Fourier series for this system of equations? The Boundary conditions are optional. I can change them if the new conditions are physically right.

Comment: With a change of coordinates the second equation can be changed into a damped wave equation. This is well studied. The solution can be plugged into the first equation to give an inhomogeneous wave equation. Again well studied. The trick will be to make it work with the bc's.

Comment: @user121049 would you please if you explain more about how to change the coordinates and decouple the system of equation?

Comment: The second equation does not have $u$ in so you can solve for $\theta$ and then substitute into the first where the term involving $\theta$ behaves as a source.   I think I made a mistake in the second when I sketched the sum out, but if you create new coordinates as linear combinations of $x$ and $t$ you can arrange to make the cross derivative go away but I doubt if you end up with the damped wave equation as I claimed.

Comment: I see you have changed a $\theta$ to a $u$. Please leave a comment when you edit a question else it can make the responses of others look strange.

Comment: @user121049 I am sorry. I forgot to leave a comment. Thanks for your answers.